# Can you create a tpl based on view page url? (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, views, theming

There's a view page which takes in taxonomy terms to display related content topic/Easter, where Easter is the term. Now in this example, I would like to create a separate TPL for that page topic/Easter. Is that possible?

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Drupal 7. Apologies for not including that. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module. Create separate views for this taxonomy term page and set it. And You can create separate template for this views.

Or You can use **hook_preprocess_views_view** for creating views template for custom view and custom view display. For ex.

```
     function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
      $view = $variables['view'];
      if($view->name == 'your_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'main_page')
   {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'views_view__viewname';
      }
```

Your template will be views-view--viewname.tpl.php in this case

Comment: I don't see that as being something I'm looking for. All that's doing is selecting a view on the term categories. I need to be able to use a TPL.

Answer (score 0):

My solution does include [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module. You will need to start off with creating a view to replace default taxonomy term view. Once that's done, you can edit view (Other section > Theme) and see what templates are being used. You can then make a copy of those templates and make changes based on your requirements. See screenshots below.

[image: Section]
[image: Theme Selection]

Please ensure that you select template specific to view otherwise the changes will be applied to all the views. In my example (Screenshot), I will create a view template like views-view--articles-admin--page.tpl.php to specifically target this view. If I make changes to views-view.tpl.php template this change will be applied to all views.

Let me know how you go.